# No connection string provided (Azure Application Insights)

Tags: spring-boot, azure, kotlin, azure-application-insights

I new to Azure App Insights. I am trying to configure it in my Spring Boot + Kotlin application. So far, after reading the guides. I have added the dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-runtime-attach -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

and in my `application.yaml` file, I added:

```
applicationinsights:
  runtime-attach:
    configuration:
      classpath:
        file: my_app_insights.json
```

My `my_app_insights.json` (resides in `src/main/resources`) contains:

```
{
  "connectionString":"A_VERY_LONG_CONNECTION_STRING",
  "sampling":{
    "requestsPerSecond":100
  },
  "instrumentation":{
    "logging":{
      "level":"INFO"
    },
    "jdbc":{
      "masking":{
        "enabled":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in my Spring Boot main class I have done this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // Attach Azure Application Insights here.
    ApplicationInsights.attach()

    runApplication<MyDownloadApplication>(*args)
}
```

But when I start my spring boot application the usual way using `mvn spring-boot:run...`

I get the following error:

```
2023-02-21 18:41:11.152+05:30 ERROR c.m.applicationinsights.agent - 
*************************
Application Insights Java Agent 3.4.9 startup failed (PID 18436)
*************************

Description:
No connection string provided

Action:
Please provide connection string.

18:41:11.582 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@306e2a0a
Feb 21, 2023 6:41:11 PM com.microsoft.applicationinsights.attach.ApplicationInsights attach
WARNING: Application Insights is already attached. It is not attached a second time.
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to add any other dependencies? Or is it the file name?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file` property can't be defined in `application.properties` or `application.yaml`. Instead, it has to be defined with `-D`, for example `-Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file=applicationinsights-dev.json`.

Another option is to no use `-Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file`. In this case, Application Insights will search an `applicationinsights.json` file in the classpath (`src/main/resources`, `src/test/resources`).

Other configuration options exist for the Application Insights json file and are given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#configuration-file-path).

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that and I still get the error. I used `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.secret.key=XXXXXX --spring.user.password=XXXXX" -Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file=applicationinsights.json`

Comment: Apologies. I got it to work with the way you mentioned. Thanks for the help. It was a problem because my pom file's `resources` tag was not dragging the json files into the classpath. To be honest, the problem just lied elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [`-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-start-parameters-details-jvmArguments) with `spring-boot:run`. For example, if you have an `applicationinsights-dev.json` file in your classpath (`src/main/resources`, `src/test/resources`), you have to execute

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file=applicationinsights-dev.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding VM argument as applicationinstights.jar, and moving applicationinsights.json file to src/main/resources, src/test/resources did work for me.