# Kotlin Springboot application is unable to find connection string for Azure Application Insight

Tags: spring-boot, azure, kotlin, azure-application-insights

I am trying to connect my Kotlin Springboot application with Azure Application Insight in local. I went through the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot. I have also consulted previous question like: [No connection string provided (Azure Application Insights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521267/no-connection-string-provided-azure-application-insights). However I am still getting the error below:
[image]

It did everything as per the documentation but it believe the error is due to this part:

> From 3.4.3, you can configure the name of a JSON file in the classpath with the applicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file system property. For example, with -Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file=applicationinsights-dev.json, Application Insights will use applicationinsights-dev.json file for configuration.

This is also the solution proposed in [No connection string provided (Azure Application Insights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521267/no-connection-string-provided-azure-application-insights).

How to get this part done and/or how to resolve this error for Application Insight version 3.4.3.

Thanks

Comment: So do you add this property to your application startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been writing the reference in the application.yaml the wrong way.
In order to help future developers, I have sent a PR to the official documentation in order to have all clear details in that documentation.
You can check my requested changes at the bottom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

- Please check all the versions that you have installed in your machine. I have installed `java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18` and applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter `2.6.4`.
- I have tried the same as per the @[jean_m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531905/20238030) thank you. I didn't find any error exception and logs are generating.

[image]

I followed the below path for my application.

- main

  - kotlin
  - resources

    - application.properties
    - applicationinsights-dev.json

[image]

- Navigate to application JAR file location and run the above command which shown in the picture.
- I can able to see triggering the logs of my kotlin application in my application insight.

[image]